# Call method from a parent class and use child class properties

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0

Actual call:

```
ChildClass classCall=new ChildClass();
classCall.FullName="test name";
string returnName=classCall.GetName();
```

Parent class with method:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        // I can request the value of the property like this.
        return this.GetType().GetProperty("FullName")
                   .GetValue(this, null).ToString();
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public partial class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public string FullName;
    public int Marks;
}
```

Question: How can I avoid hardcoding the property name, i.e. `GetProperty("FullName")`. I don't want to hardcode the property name, rather use some other approach and use it in parent method?

Comment: No; that is *wrong*. Why on earth are you using reflection for this? Why not just use polymorphism; or put "FullName" in the base class?

Comment: If you have multiple entity object class created, the EF auto generates those properties from tables, in that case
i would like to create a partial class for each entity, have a base class, write a common method in the base class, then let use 1 method across for multiple child classes.

Comment: @Sharpeye500: But your base class is only going to work when the tables have a `FullName` property, right? So that logically belongs in the base class.

Comment: So modify the T4 templates to derive from your base class; or just extend the partial generated classes! You shouldn't need reflection here.

Comment: Thanks, any quick sample example will help, thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, I'd suggest avoiding using public fields - use properties if you want to make state public. (You're *asking* for a property in your reflection call, but your derived class declares a field...)

At that point, you can make `FullName` an *abstract* property in the base class, and allow each derived class to implement it however they want - but you can still call it from the base class.

On the other hand, if every derived class is going to have to implement it, why not just pass it into the base class's constructor? Either the class makes sense without a `FullName` or it doesn't - your current code will break if there *isn't* a `FullName` field, so why not have it in the base class to start with?

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual string GetName()
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public partial class ChildClass : BaseClass
    {

        public string FullName;
        public int Marks;

        public override string GetName()
        {
            return FullName;
        }
    }
```

However, if you never want to initialize a BaseClass object you want to make it abstract and force everybody who implements it to implement its own version of the GetName method:

```
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public abstract string GetName();
    }
```

BR

Comment: Hiding is nearly never preferred to overriding. Why aren't you using 'virtual'?

Comment: Helping somebody implement a really bad design in a slightly less crazy way isn't a great idea. It would be much better to show him how to achieve the same design goal by using appropriate language features. In this case, `FullName` should be a virtual or abstract property, and `GetName()` should not exist at all. As above, `new` is almost never preferable to `virtual`, and absolutely is not in this case, even if `GetName()` did have any reason to exist.

Comment: of course you are right. first approach was to change his code as few as possible since i don't know anything about his domain. however i included your feedback now. :/